# Laravel | Errors in validation | The category field is required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

the problem is when i click on submit button of the form it appears

> The category.0.abbr field is required

This is my request code

```
 public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
           'photo' => 'required_without:id|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
            'category' => 'required|array|min:1',
            'category.*.name' => 'required',
            'category.*.abbr' => 'required',
            'category.*.active' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

And this is my code in controller file

```
   public function store(MainCategoryRequest $request)
{

    //return request;
   $main_categories = collect($request -> category);

    $filter = $main_categories->filter(function ($value,$key){
       return $value['$abbr'] == get_default_lang();
   });

   return $default_category = array_values($filter -> all()) ;

}
```

And this is my html code

```
<form class="form" action="{{route('admin.maincategories.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
{{__('messages.'.$lang -> abbr)}}</label>
<input type="text" value="" id="abbr" class="form-control"placeholder=""name="category[{{$index}}][abbr]">
                                                                           
                                                                           
         @error("category.$index.abbr")
        <span class="text-danger">{{$message}}</span>
        @enderror

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="la la-check-square-o"></i> save
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It need to be like this

```
<input type="text" value="" id="abbr" class="form-control"placeholder=""name="category[{{$index}}][abbr]">
```

Comment: i did it but it does not work

Comment: Ya, it will return errors but now for name and active inputs, not abbr